# Replace foreach with a pipeline

Tags: powershell

Ok, say I have a bunch of text files in a directory tree, all with the same name, and I want to concatenate them all into 1 file.

I got it working with a foreach, but I was wondering if there were a better way to use the pipleline.

Is there a better way to do this?

Code:

```
dir -filter users.txt -recurse | foreach { get-content $_.FullName | add-content .\All.txt }
```

That worked, but I felt like I should have been able to do it without the foreach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you read the help for `Get-Content` you will see that `-Path` accepts string[] array, which means that you can try to pipe the output from Get-ChildItem directly in.

```
[22:24:57] PS-ADMIN> get-help Get-Content

NAME
    Get-Content

SYNOPSIS
    Gets the contents of a file.

SYNTAX
    Get-Content [-Path] <String[]> [-Credential <PSCredential>] ......
```

So try this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter users.txt -Recurse | Get-Content | Set-Content .\all.txt
```

EDIT: Actually: after researching more, I've found that it's `-LiteralPath` that's taking the `PSPath` properties from the FileInfo-objects and uses that as path. Still, same logic :-)

Comment: Thanks!  I could have sworn that I had tried that before posting and gotten a file that was just filled with "users.txt".  I must have done something wrong the first time, because when I tried it again, it worked great.